# How should I create "screen sharing" with SignalR

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr-hub

I know this is not a specific question, but I just want to get design ideas about a `screen sharing` web site with `SignalR`.

We want to add a link on our website which is called "Share My Screen" and then our `support team` be able to see the content of the browser (not whole desktop) and even they be able to click or type on `customer browser`.

I was thinking to do it as

1. Taking `screen shot` from browser by `js` (by http://html2canvas.hertzen.com for example)
2. send taken `screen shot` to server constantly (I don't know how yet)
3. Server sends the received `screen shot` to our `support team` browser
4. Capturing `mouse move` and `key press` on `support team` browser
5. Sending this captured data to `customer browser`

Since each part of this needs a lot of work I just want to gather all possible ideas to find a tested solution

Comment: Save yourself the heartbreak and just use go to meeting or something.

Comment: @Will Yeah, but since our clients are old people, our company wants to have it's implementation without using any other software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I do not think your idea of `capturing screen` is really doable with javascript technology. Security would be a huge issue, you would need to process a high amount of data, and syncing events would be a nightmare no matter how you approach it. Capturing and sharing `tab content` and `events` is a much more manageable goal.

If you are aiming to use this for people who can not manage to install a `remote control` app, then we can count newer technologies such as [`WebRTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC) out due to  [browser compatibility issues](http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc).

There is a good blog post discussing this issue [**here** - (Screensharing a browser tab in HTML5?)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/).

I especially like the first method, using [`Mutation Observer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) [(browser support)](http://caniuse.com/#search=mutation%20observer) and [`Web Sockets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) [(browser support)](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20sockets). It basically syncs two html documents through the use of [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and uses [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) for communication. You could use `SignalR` instead of standard web socket API for communication if you prefer.